# Align vertically images hover img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a grid of images with same width but with diferent height.

On hover the image i want to display two differnt links to get info of the image and the author.

The problem is i can't vertical aling the links over the image :/

HTML:

```
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="img-work">
                        <img src="img/grid1.jpg" alt="" class="img-grid">
                        <a href="#" class="zoom"">
                            <img src="img/hover-item.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="info">
                            <img src="img/hover-info.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.img-work a.zoom {
   left: 31%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 27%;
   visibility: hidden;
   width: 38px;
}
div.img-work a.info {
   left: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 27%;
   visibility: hidden;
   width: 39px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
    $('div.img-work').hover(function() {
        $(this).children('a').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $(this).children('img').css('opacity', '0.5');
    }, function() {
        $(this).children('a').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $(this).children('img').css('opacity', '1');
    });
```

As you can't see i don't how to align those link vertically . Any hints would be appreciate. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here's a CSS solution: http://jsfiddle.net/08vorn1s/.

The images are vertically and horizontally centered within their container.  You can easily adjust the code if the images need to be bottom-aligned.

HTML:

```
<div class = "grid">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "cell">
            <img src = "http://placehold.it/150x150 " />
            <div class = "links">
                <a href = "#">Info</a>
                <a href = "#">Author</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "cell">
            <img src = "http://placehold.it/150x170 " />
            <div class = "links">
                <a href = "#">Info</a>
                <a href = "#">Author</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "cell">
            <img src = "http://placehold.it/150x200 " />
            <div class = "links">
                <a href = "#">Info</a>
                <a href = "#">Author</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

.grid {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.grid .row {
    display: table-row;
}

.grid .row .cell {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}

.cell > .links {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    display: none;
}

.cell:hover > img {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.cell:hover > .links {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your property like so `position: relative`? You might also want to adjust your `left` and `top` CSS properties based on image size.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.item` element needs to have a `position: relative;` and your overlay element (`.info`) needs to have:

```
position: absolute;
top:0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: block;
```